# Cassandra: create JSON column using cdlsh

Tags: json, cassandra, cqlsh

lets say I have a a table when one of the columns is JSON.
like
a:text
b:text
c:

How could I define such table in Cassandra so I will be able to make
select * from table where c.d=something??

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra does not, as normally used, decode or interpret your JSON for you. Some of the other popular "NoSQL" tools do; maybe you're thinking of something else, or you want to use something else?

The right way to solve your problem in Cassandra isn't clear from what you've stated. Is "d" an attribute that all or many of your records will have, or is it meant to stand for an arbitrary attribute lookup?

It's important with Cassandra to have a good understanding of what you're going to need to query when you're designing the model, unlike with, say, a relational DB, where you often just need to know the structure and relationships of your data.

Comment: My JSON is like
a={b=c,d=e}.
My question is - may I define a composite field in Cassandra that will include the JSON value into it, and after that will permit me to do a selects like
select * from table where field.b=c and field.d=e ?